# Check column and copy if it is the same

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers in the Range G2:G10, I have to check if these numbers are in one of the Cells in the Row B of the second file. Now I just have a true if argument when the same number is in G2(File 1) and B2(File 2). But how can I do this, so that when G2(File 1) and B4(File 2) are the same the if also works?

```
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\Map2.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\file.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet1")



    For Each cell In wb1.Sheets(1).Range("G2:G10")
        If cell.Value = ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value Then

            ws2.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Resize(1, 3).Select

        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rick, I'm confused, you want to check is G4 is equal to B2 or B2 to G2. Your ask got a little messy. If you want to compare B2 to G4, when you write `cell.row` just add `+2`?

Comment: Hi @MarkS. Sorrry my english is not the best. I have G2:G10 in this are numbers. I have to compare these numbers with the whole row B at the File 2. Now the if statement only works if the G2 and B2 are similar numbers. But i have to control the whole row B. So when the similar number is in B15 i have to copy this. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: No I don't. You need to compare the value of 1 cell (at a time) from one spreadsheet against several cells in a whole column (not row?). I need clarification, you want to compare `B2` to the sum of `G2:G10`?

Comment: I have G2:G10. In this cells are numbers. For example in the cell G2 is the number 20. I have to check if the number 20 is also in a cell in the whole Row B. So for example the 20 is in the B11 then i have to copy the cell next to it. When the 20 is in B256 i have to Copy the cell next to it. Now it just works when the 20 is in G2 and B2. But when the 20 are in the B3 it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range, cx As Range, str$
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\Map2.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\file.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet1")

    For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 7), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
        For Each cx In ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 2), ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            If c = cx Then
                cx.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 3).Select
                str = str & ", " & cx.Address
                'Msgbox cx.Address
            End If
        Next cx
    Next c
    Msgbox "The following cells meet the conditions: " & Replace(str, ",", "", 1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i get an runtime error 1004 at line `For Each c In ws1.Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))` maybe you now something?

Comment: ```Cells``` and ```rows.count``` has no reference it is using the active sheet, so your range is looking at one sheet while the values the range consists of is getting it from the other sheet.

Comment: @Rick try now then

Comment: @Rick feel free to accept my answer if it solves your problem

Comment: @AsUsual i have the problem, that when i execute this, the makro will just do one cell but it don't go down to the next. Do i something wrong?

Comment: @Rick Could it be that you're only seeing the result of the last revolution of the loop? Try the edited code, maybe apply the Msgbox within the loop to see each result of it.

Comment: @AsUsual i found the problem.. my numbers was saved as text..

Answer (score 0):

This uses a dictionary and does what I think you are looking for. Though I might have your sheets backwards. I tested using a single workbook and just added in your workbook and sheet values. I am also unsure what you want to do when a value is found so I left that blank.

```
Sub compare()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim dict As Object

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\Map2.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("T:\folder\file.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet1")

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'This is late bound you can change to early binding if you want
    With ws2
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In .Range("B1:B" & lastrow)
            If Not dict.exists(cell.Value) Then 'Avoid errors
                dict.Add cell.Value,cell 'Add key value, item will be the range
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

    With ws1
        For Each cell In Range("G2:G10")
            If dict.exists(cell.Value) Then 'Duplicate found when true
            'Here we take the matched range offset and place it in the new offset range
                Range(cell.Offset(0, 2), cell.Offset(0, 4)).Value = Range(dict(cell.Value).Offset(0, 2), dict(cell.Value).Offset(0, 4)).Value
            End If
        Next cell
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, when the cell in G2:G10 is similar as one of the cells in row B i have to copy the cell next to the similar cell in row B.

Comment: So if ```G2``` matches with ```B4``` you want to grab ```B3``` and ```B5```? Or is it ```A4``` and ```C4```? Where do those get pasted?

Comment: When G2 (File1) matches with B4(File2) then i have to copy D,E and F next to B4 from file2 to cell I,J and K in file 1 next to G2

Comment: Okay added in an edit, the dictionary item is now ```cell``` which we use to get the offset value, and place that in the offset of the matched cell.

Comment: thanks a lot, when i execute the makro, it would.'t do anything..

Comment: step through the code by pressing f8 it might be not matching anything. Are there any preceding or trailing spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i will write you tomorrow when i work again